# Keep getting keypad codes instead character input from the keyboard in Java

Tags: java

I keep having an issue when I enter a key on the keyboard it keeps returning the keypad codes for example when I press 1 it returns a value of `49` I have tried changing the data type to use `char` and the issue is still occuring. It only seems to output the keypad code in one of my methods but not for the `addKeyListener` method I have. When I printed out the `SETSIZE` variable it return the correct input, however in my method called `assignMove` the `num` parameter keeps outputting the keypad code, and I'm not sure why. Would appreciate the help.

PanelCell Class

```
private GamePanel panel;
private int row;
private int col;
public static final char SETSIZE = 5;

    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        char SETSIZE = e.getKeyChar();
        panel.assignMove(row, col, SETSIZE);
      }
    });
```

GamePanel Class

```
  void assignMove(int row, int col, int num)
  {
   System.out.print(num);   
   if ((row<1) || (row>Futoshiki.SETSIZE)) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
            "invalid row (" + row + ")", 
            "Futoshiki",   
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);  
      throw new FutoshikiException("invalid row (" + row + ")");
    }
          
   if ((col<1) || (col>Futoshiki.SETSIZE)) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
            "invalid column (" + col + ")", 
            "Futoshiki",   
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION); 
      throw new FutoshikiException("invalid column (" + col + ")");
    }
    
   if (game.isAssigned(row, col)) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
            "the cell at (" + row + "," + col + ") is assigned (" + game.getNum(row,col) + ")", 
            "Futoshiki",   
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);  
      throw new FutoshikiException("the cell at (" + row + "," + col + ") is assigned (" + game.getNum(row,col) + ")");
    }
          
   if ((num<1) || (num>Futoshiki.SETSIZE)) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
            "invalid value " + num, 
            "Futoshiki",   
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);   
      throw new FutoshikiException("invalid value " + num);
    }
    
   if (!game.isValidAssign(row, col, num)) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
            "invalid value assignment " + row + " " + col + " " + num, 
            "Futoshiki",   
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
      throw new FutoshikiException("invalid value assignment " + row + " " + col + " " + num);
    }
    
   Assign userMove = new Assign(row, col, num);
   System.out.print("row " + row + " " + "col "+ col + " " + "num " + num);
   game.assign(userMove);
  }
```

Comment: it's called Widening Primitive Conversion. The compiler converts your char to int, because, as @vidyasagar says, your third argument for the assignMove method is an int. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char` is a primitive type in Java. It is a 16 bit, unsigned integer that represents a Unicode code point. It does not contain the value that appears on the keyboard.

You can use the methods of class `java.lang.Character` to get the "keyboard" value.

```java
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        char ch = e.getKeyChar();
        if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            panel.assignMove(row, col, Character.getNumericValue(ch));
        }
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can simply check the value.

```java
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        char ch = e.getKeyChar();
        int val = (int) ch;
        if (val >= 48  &&  val <= 57) {
            panel.assignMove(row, col, val - 48);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `char num` in the `assignMove` method instead of `int num`. Because your `num` parameter is an `int`, the `char` value that is being passed will typecast to `int` which will be the ASCII code.

Sample:

```
void assignMove(int row, int col, char num)
```

Comment: When I change num to a `char` it breaks the validation to check if the number is valid it's this if statement `if ((num<1) || (num>Futoshiki.SETSIZE)) `

Comment: you can pass `num - 48` in every place where the num is being used.

```if ((num - 48 <1) || (num - 48 >Futoshiki.SETSIZE))```